# Retag [interesting-tags] to [favorite-tags]

Tags: support, status-completed, meta, retag-request

With interesting tags being [renamed to favorite tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/tag-favorites-and-tag-subscriptions/), the appropriate change should be made from [interesting-tags](/questions/tagged/interesting-tags) to [favorite-tags](/questions/tagged/favorite-tags) on Meta Stack Exchange and all per-site metas.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interesting tags became Favorite Tags; when will references be changed over?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95973/interesting-tags-became-favorite-tags-when-will-references-be-changed-over)

Answer (score 1):

Agreed. In this case, however, it's probably too much work to go back and edit all the questions to change the terminology... might as well leave it alone and deal with the 1 or 2 questions about the discrepancy.

Also, since the feature has been around for so long, I think it makes sense to create a synonym that maps [interesting-tags](/questions/tagged/interesting-tags) to [favorite-tags](/questions/tagged/favorite-tags). We'll likely end up doing that eventually anyway, so mess-prevention now is a good plan.