# Interesting tags became Favorite Tags; when will references be changed over?

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, tag-watching

As usual, being behind the times, I just found out today that Interesting Tags are now called Favorite Tags, while wondering why so many people kept calling them favorite.  Of course this sucks because there are thousands of references to Interesting Tags, and now this creates confusion between Favorite Questions and Favorite Tags (definitely violates the rule of [Positioning](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071373586)).

When is the team going to do a mass changeover so that all Interesting Tags references (words and tags) are now Favorite Tags references?

This [related post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74592/retag-interesting-tags-to-favorite-tags) led me to the [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/tag-favorites-and-tag-subscriptions/) which was done in January.  Does it really take five months to whip this out?

Comment: Wow, I really don't understand those who want to create messes and not clean them up.  It's an alien thought process to me.  But hey, I've seen a lot of code like that.

Answer (score 1):

[Sure](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/005361.html) [can't](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medireview) [see](http://blog.oup.com/2007/11/spellchecker/) [how](http://boards.theforce.net/your_jedi_council_community/b10008/28670004/p1/?23) that could go [wrong](http://www.flickr.com/photos/marnanel/211728740/).

Comment: Guess they better do it right then.

Comment: A lot of people tried to make Q&A sites too and failed, maybe they shouldn't have even tried with SO.

Comment: Lance, you dislike the original change. We get it.

Comment: No, Michael, you don't get it. It's not about what I like. While the change was bad, the POINT is that they need to cleanup to go with the change.  Like changing a procedure name in your code, you go change all the references to it.  Please read what I said and don't make assumptions, I was explicit.

Comment: Lance, I know what you wrote. I'm struggling with whether you're pulling our collective leg. I'm still not sure. If you are, then I'll just state: some changes are clearly not worth the effort and risk.

Comment: @Michael ~ He's not, that's just Lance. He wants it to be 100% perfect.

Comment: @Michael, I don't expect perfection, I expect work.  But then again, how hard is it for them to make a tag synonym?  The tags could have been switched over immediately.  Now it will be years before the new tag overtakes the old one, so that I can create the synonym.  Then they could do a few basic things, and cut down on the big stuff.  Then it will be hand work, and people like me will work those issues.  They made a change without thinking about the consequences.