# Give us a way to search for synonymed tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms, search

Someone [finally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95973/interesting-tags-became-favorite-tags-when-will-references-be-changed-over) created a synonym for [interesting-tags](/questions/tagged/interesting-tags) to [favorite-tags](/questions/tagged/favorite-tags).

It shows that there are still 146 questions with the old tag on them.  I know the Team is unwilling to go change these (as per my linked question), so I figured I'd start in on it now that the tag has been synonymized.  But lo and behold, it turns out that when you search on a synonymed tag it takes you to the master tag search page, so I'm unable to list the questions with the old tag using Search, so that I can do the conversions.

Please give us a way to specifically do an advanced search for the tag without going to the master.

**NOTE:**  You can get to the specific tag search page if you click on the tag itself, so the logic is in there.  This also means that this is just a minor feature request, since it can be worked around.

Comment: so... what are you unable to do here? Post URLs...

Comment: Now that I've found the workaround, there is nothing I'm unable to do.  I just think the advanced search capabilities should be complete.  Newer users shouldn't have to find the trick, they should just see the instructions on the AS page.

Comment: The "trick" in this case being *clicking on the tag*? This seems exceedingly obscure...

Comment: Just for new users, which is why I said it was only minor.  Much more than that for AS we really need `deleted` and `locked` searches.

Comment: Why should we be helping new users search for the *wrong* tag?

Comment: Good Question :), probably so they can do suggested edits and help us out.  It will take me weeks to clean up this tag manually.

Comment: As far as I know (at least, this is true on SO), the newly synonymized tags are automatically retagged by some script. You just have to have some patience.

Comment: @Chichiray, no, I think they have to manually batch retag them, which is why I brought up the linked question in the first place, because they haven't bothered to do it.

Comment: @Shog9, thanks for the batch retag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality to search by tag synonym is also converted to perform a search by the master tag. Take, for example, [markdown-rendering](/questions/tagged/markdown-rendering) (currently having 193 posts associated with it) which is a synonym of the master [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown) (with 1,568 posts associated with it):

[image]

Clicking on either will show posts under *both* [markdown-rendering](/questions/tagged/markdown-rendering) and [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown) (a total of 193 + 1,568 = 1761 posts):

[image]

Sifting through this list when the tags a more heavily weighted towards the master doesn't help. Currently, the only way to achieve this in some reasonable form is via [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com). Specifically, here's a query that does that: [Find questions by tags](//data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/510521/find-questions-by-tags). As [an example](//data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/510521/find-questions-by-tags?Tag1=markdown-rendering&Limit=200):

[image]