# The [interesting-tags] tag should not be a default tag on Meta sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, per-site-meta, default-tags

The tag [interesting-tags](/questions/tagged/interesting-tags) is one of the [default tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62655/add-a-selection-of-default-tags-to-all-metas) which are automatically imported to a local meta when a new site is created. (And cannot be removed, even if they are not used in any questions.)

However, as you can see on this site it is [a synonym of (favorite tags)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/favorite-tags/synonyms). (Which probably was not the case at the time when the set of default tags were selected.) And I guess most users know this feature under the name *favorite tags* rather than *interesting tags*.

As a result on most local metas this tag either remain unused of is used in entirely different meaning - obviously it was intended as a tag for questions about [favorite-tags](/questions/tagged/favorite-tags). You can check for yourself on the meta sites you frequent, or you can even [browse a few local metas](https://www.google.com/search?q="tagged%2Finteresting-tags"+site%3Ameta.stackexchange.com) if you want to check that this is indeed the case.

For already existing sites, there is probably not much that can be done about this. (Perhaps developers or members of the SE team could be able to tell whether it is possible to change this also retroactively.)

But I would suggest that at least in the future when a new site is created, meta should be populated with (favorite-tags) in the selection of default tags.

**[TL;DR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TL;DR):** My proposal is to replace [interesting-tags](/questions/tagged/interesting-tags) by [favorite-tags](/questions/tagged/favorite-tags) in the selection of default tags that are added to every newly created local meta.

Comment: I will just mention that ([tag:favorite-tags]) is now called ([tag:tag-watching]). See also: ['Favorite Tags' is now 'Tag Watching'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312180).

Comment: This is marked ([tag:status-completed]), but I am not really sure whether the list of default tags has changed in any way: [Retag \[interesting-tags\] to \[favorite-tags\]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74592).

Comment: I just noticed this myself. I think regardless, [interesting-tags] should not be a default tag. We could have a [tag-watching] default tag in its place, or we could just not replace it with anything as well.

Comment: @Martin I think the completed tag means that it was change for all sites that existed at the time, but nothing was changed for new sites.

Comment: A related feature-request (that includes the same suggestion in a parenthetical at the end): [Please remove some redundant tags from the list of default tags on child metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234473/335251)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm sure if we waited a bit longer, we could redesign/rename that feature at least one more time. :)

Alas. We removed [interesting-tags](/questions/tagged/interesting-tags) from the list of default tags created on new meta sites since it's been years since it was relevant, and there's no particularly strong evidence for [tag-watching](/questions/tagged/tag-watching) being relevant either.